# C# Синхронизированный доступ к списку

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, синхронизация

Имеется задача:

Родительская нить программы должна считывать вводимые пользователем строки и помещать их в начало связанного списка. Строки длиннее 80 символов можно разрезать на несколько строк. При вводе пустой строки программа должна выдавать текущее состояние списка. Дочерняя нить пробуждается каждые пять секунд и сортирует список в лексикографическом порядке (используйте пузырьковую сортировку). Все операции над списком должны синхронизоваться при помощи мутекса.

как я могу решить данную задачу? Подскажите с чего начать.

Comment: Начните с функции `Main`.

Comment: Начните с основ работы с потоками - запуска их, приостановки на время (Sleep), объектов синхронизации (mutex).

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно как-то так:

```
IEnumerable<string> InputLines()
{
    while (true) yield return Console.ReadLine();
}

List<string> lines = new List<string>();

foreach (var l in InputLines())
    lock (mutex)
        if (l == "") Output(lines); else lines.Add(l);

// в новом потоке
while (true)
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    lock (mutex) lines.Sort();
}
```

Разбирайтесь.

Comment: говорят mutex - ненастоящий! :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Воспользуемся duck typing'ом: если по нему можно лочить, то он мьютекс :)